# Converting UTF-8 Characters to Upper/Lower case C++

Tags: c++, linux, windows, unicode, cross-platform

I have a string that contains UTF-8 Characters, and I have a method that is supposed to convert every character to either upper or lower case, this is easily done with characters that overlap with ASCII, and obviously some characters cannot be converted, e.g. any Chinese character. However is there a good way to detect and convert other characters that can be Upper/Lower, e.g. all the greek characters? Also please note that I need to be able to do this on both Windows and Linux.

Thank you,

Comment: It is important to get the terminology correct here in order to get a useful answer. UTF-8 is a character encoding specified in RFC 3629 (and elsewhere); it contains algorithms for mapping between unicode characters and octet sequences that represent those characters portably. Please be precise with types; even better, show the code that includes the declarations and types.

Comment: Greg your comment makes no sense to me, sorry but I don't have any code yet I am trying to figure out how to do something, not trying to debug something that is not correctly working so that makes no sense to me, also I know UTF-8 is an encoding, but that really don't change what I am trying to achieve which is develop a means by which to go from "a" -> "A" or from "Ω" -> "ω"

Comment: What is the purpose? Do you intend to use it to compare such processed strings? I am assuming you do want to use it for such comparison. Do you realise that this will not handle things like "ß" and "ss" being equivalent in German?

Answer (score 16):

Have a look at [ICU](http://site.icu-project.org/).

Note that lower case to upper case functions are locale-dependant. Think about the turkish (ascii) letter I which gets "dotless lowercase i" and (ascii) i which gets "uppercase I with a dot".

Comment: Thank you for the tip Alexandre, however I am precluded for this application from linking against any 3rd party libs. So I need to figure out how to do this with with out using that lib.

Comment: I suggest that you write you roll your own case mapping utility, check out http://www.unicode.org/faq/casemap_charprop.html. From there you can download all the special case mappings.

Comment: C++ has no unicode support whatsoever. ICU is *the* way to go.

Comment: @NSA: Why can you not link against another library?

Comment: @NSA you can link statically against ICU. You could re-implement it, but why? Perhaps you can explain more about your preclusion.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you have access to wctype.h, then convert your text to a 2-byte unicode string and use towupper(). Then convert it back to UTF-8.

Comment: or use ICU as Alexandre mentioned.

Comment: @Alexandre C.: Whether or not characters like that get converted correctly depends entirely on the current locale.

Comment: @Alexandre C: Even stronger, what _is_ correct depends on the locale. Your opinion on what correct just isn't shared by the whole world; the most famous example being the Turkish i.

Comment: @caf, @MSalters: In the German eszett case, capital B is SS (ie two characters, obviously not handled by towupper), and for the greek capital sigma, there are two different choices depending whether it is at the end of a word or not (so not handled by towlower). Again, ICU solve these problems.

Comment: Minor note: on many systems, including Linux, `wchar_t` is four bytes wide, not two. Indeed, the standard requires it to be wider than two bytes, and Microsoft just decided not to break the Windows API for the sake of the C standard. If your `wchar_t` is two bytes long, it is UTF-16. also a multi-byte encoding, and converting to a single wide character is not enough.

Comment: @Davislor: I am not saying you are wrong, I am curious: Where, in your opinion, does the C standard *require* wchar_t to be more than two bytes? It needs to hold a wide character *in the widest supported locale*. If an implementation decides to only support UCS-2 (basically, UTF-16 without the surrogate pairs), a 16-bit wchar_t is fine... or am I mistaken?

Comment: @DevSolar Without putting a lengthy rant in these comments, it basically comes down to UTF-16 not being a fixed-width encoding. (Because UCS-2 originally was, then had to be extended without breaking compatibility.) So, there are multibyte characters and characters in some supported locales that do not fit into a single wide character on Windows, which the Standard theoretically requires. The `towupeer()` function and its like are one thing that breaks.

Comment: @Davislor: I understand that. But if an implementation states that it *supports* only UCS-2 (as Microsoft did for a time), and does not support any wider charset, then the standard does not *require* a wider-than-16bit `wchar_t`; are we in agreement on that? (BTW, what is the current situation re: Windows / wchar_t? Are they using it for UTF-16 including surrogate pairs and basically ignore that "wide" is supposed to mean "wide" instead of "wider multibyte"?)

Comment: @DevSolar In Windows, `wchar_t` is the system `WCHAR` type from the Windows Unicode API, which is now UTF-16. In theory, an implementation shouldn't support any locale containing characters that cannot be mapped to a distinct `wchar_t` value. So, for UTF-16, that would mean no characters outside the BMP, in any locale. In practice, for instance, Code Page 54936 supports Chinese characters from GB 18030 from the supplementary ideographic planes.

Answer (score 0):

On Linux, or with a standard library that supports it, you would obtain a `std::locale` object for the appropriate locale, as uppercase conversion is locale-specific.  Convert each UTF-8 character to a `wchar_t`, then call `std::toupper()` on it, then convert back to UTF-8.  Note that the resulting string might be longer or shorter, and some ligatures might not work properly: ß to Ss in German is the example everyone keeps bringing up.

On Windows, this approach will work even less of the time, because wide characters are UTF-16 and not a fixed-width encoding (which violates the C++ language standard, but then maybe the standards committee shouldn't have tried to bluff Microsoft into breaking the Windows API).  There is a `ToUpper` method in the CLR.

It is probably easier to use a portable library such as ICU.

Also make sure whether what you want is uppercase (capitalizing every letter) or titlecase (capitalizing the first letter of a string, or the first part of a ligature).